# Splitting a mysql column into multiple columns in another table after regexp

Tags: mysql

I have a field "Name" that has the name formatted like First_Last in Table1. I have a new table called Table2 that is a copy of Table1, but Name has been replaced by 2 new columns: FirstName, LastName.

I have been using REGEXP_SUBSTR() in order to split the name into the first and last, but I can't figure out how to send these values into my new table.

Comment: Please post table structure and data sample. Also post your attempted query and expected result.

Comment: Table1 has only 1 column, "Name", with 1 row of value "First_Last", Table2 has 2 columns, "FirstName", then "LastName".

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: Then, how is the data look like in `First_Last` column of `table1`? And how consistent is it? And how did you attempt with using `REGEXP_SUBSTR()`? Did the query with `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` run successful but not with your expected output? These are some of the follow-up questions I have right now. Can you include those info [into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69701799/edit)? Thanks

Comment: **Show us what you’ve done so far** so that we have something to start with. It’s much easier for us to help you with existing code, and people are far more likely to help when they don’t have to start from zero with "How do I do this?"